# How to set minimum width of all the controls in application in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a application that uses 1000 controls.How do I set minimum width of all these controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say with default style, but there's a lot of controls, which overrides theirs default style. So probably the most efficient way would be to create 'base' style

```
<Style TargetType="FrameworkElement" x:Key="BaseStyle">
   <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="30" />
</Style>
```

And/or set style for each type of your elements with global style (without x:Key), and with exact style (with key), where you need that.
Global style for button, for example:

```
 <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
    <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="50" />
 </Style>
```